# Handling Timestamps Python Panda

Tags: python, pandas, date, graph

I am new to Python and trying to learn as much as I can.
I am trying to create a live graph with Matplotlib by reading from a CSV file.
It seems that I am having a TypeError: value, I am guessing from the timestamp format.
From what I read on Pandas infobase, The date_parser should take care of this, but i am unsure on using properly.

I would like to use the Timestamp in the 2nd column of the CSV as the X Axis, and then plot the rest of the data as Y values.

The CSV looks like this:

```
1,11:24:30,null,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
1,11:24:33,null,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
1,11:24:35,null,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
1,11:24:38,null,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
1,11:24:41,null,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
1,11:24:43,null,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
```

My code is below:

```
import random
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

index = count()


def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv('C:/Python/20220124.csv', names=["Pass", "Time", "1", "2"], header= 
    None, parse_dates= True)
    y1 = data['Pass']
    y2 = data['Time']
    y3 = data['1']
    y4 = data['2']

    plt.cla()

    plt.plot(y1, label='Pass/Fail', lw=3, c='c', marker='o', markersize=4, mfc='k')
    plt.plot(y2, label='Time', lw=3, c='c', marker='o', markersize=4, mfc='k')
    plt.plot(y3, label='1', lw=2, ls='--', c='k')
    plt.plot(y4, label='2', lw=2, ls='--',  c='k')

    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.tight_layout()

    ax = plt.gca()

    xlim_low, xlim_high = ax.get_xlim()

    ax.set_xlim(xlim_low, xlim_high)

    y1offset = 1.0
    y1max = (y4.max() + y1offset)
    current_ymax = y1max

    y1min = (y3.min() - y1offset)
    current_ymin = y1min

    ax.set_ylim(current_ymin, current_ymax)



ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It would be useful to have the full Traceback

Answer (score 0):

*I state that I am not an expert on pandas or matplotlib.*

Looking at your code I think that the problem lies in the data definition of the CSV file.
You pass to `read_csv` the array `names` with 4 fields, but your CSV has lots more columns.

Trying your code, if I remove from the CSV the data in excess and use only four fields per line the plot is drawn.

As I stated, I don't know these libraries, but as I understood pandas `read_csv` is used to load data into a data structure (the `DataFrame` as I read from the docs).
Something probably is going wrong when the function attempts to read more data and parse them as timestamps producing the TypeError.

But is a big guess, I think is better to go back to the Pandas docs!